# Returning a result of type boolean in Java

Tags: java, boolean

I'm trying to solve this question:

Write a method named areFactors that takes an integer n
and an array of integers, and that returns true if the numbers in the array
are all factors of n (which is to say that n is divisible by all of them).

This is one of my answer which works:

```
public static boolean arefactors(int n, int[] factors){
    for (int factor:factors){
       if (n % factor != 0)
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But why when I reverse and return 'true' first, the program doesn't work properly and always return true regardless of what integer I use in the array? In this case:

```
public static boolean areFactors( int n, int[] factors) {
    for (int factor: factors) {
        if ( n % factor==0) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In the first example, your method returns TRUE if ALL elements of the array are factors of N. In the second case, your method returns TRUE if 1 element is. And by 1 I mean just any 1 element from the array. The first one is what you need.

Comment: Think about what it means to return from a function. You said you need to test all the numbers in the array - does your second code snippet do that?

Comment: Appropriate indentation makes your code much easier to follow.

Answer (score 2):

In the first method you return `true` if **all** of the numbers in the `factors` array are factors of `n` (i.e. you return `false` if any of the numbers is **not** a factor, which means you return `true` only if you finished checking all the numbers).

In the second method you return `true` if **any** of the numbers in the `factors` array is a factor of `n` (since you return `true` the first time you find a factor of `n`).

Hence the two methods produce a different output.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have to return `true` only as all `int`s of the `factors` array are divisible by `n`.
But you return `true` at the first matching in the second code :

```
public static boolean areFactors( int n, int[] factors) {
for (int factor: factors) {
    if ( n % factor==0) 
        return true; // only first element(s) of factors may be divisible 
                     // by n and not the next one. But too late you returned true
    }
    return false;
}
```

While your first code is correct :

```
public static boolean arefactors(int n, int[] factors){
    for (int factor:factors){
       if (n % factor != 0)
           return false;  // if any is not divisible by n, you return false
    }
    return true; // if you go there, it means all numbers are divisible by n
                 // you can then return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code doesn't work properly because:

This

```
if ( n % factor != 0 )
```

should be

```
if ( factor % n != 0 )
```